# To access the detail page by searching on list of lists

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list and a detail page for each one with the route I created with onGenerateRoute.

My data source is a list of lists.

```
final MyDataList=<List>[

  //[0][0]  _teamName
  //[0][1]   _info
  //[0][2]  _info2

  ["team1 name","team_1  first info","team_1 second info"],
  ["team2 name","info..","info2.."],
  ["abc team","abc's info","info2"],
  ["xyz ","info","info2"],
  ["klmn","infoklmn","info2klmn"],

];
```

I want to search teamName in MyDataList. Here instead of `aSingleList.where((p)` . MyDataList is list of lists, I couldn't find how to do this.(here is where I want to search==> MyDataList[i][0] i==>team names)

```
    @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {}
  
List<String> aSingleList=["a","single","list","."];  //example: a normal list

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? [" "]
        : aSingleList.where((p) => p.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
    //There is no problem with such a list.
    //But here is where I want to search==> MyDataList[i][0] 

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        //onTap: (){},  How can I go to the detail page of the found team name?

        title: Text(suggestionList[index]),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
```

detail_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:teams/main.dart';
import 'package:teams/team_model.dart';


class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  int incomingIndex;
  TeamModel chosenTeam;

  DetailPage(this.incomingIndex);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    chosenTeam = TeamList.allTeams[incomingIndex];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(chosenTeam.teamName),
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(text: "tab1",),
              Tab(text: "tab2",),

            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView( child: Center(child: Text(chosenTeam.info,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),))),
              SingleChildScrollView(child: Center(child: Text(chosenTeam.info2,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),))),

            ],
          )),
    );
  }

}
```

team_model.dart

```
class TeamModel{   //model

  String _teamName;
  String _info;
  String _info2;

  TeamModel(this._teamName,this._info,this._info2);


  String get teamName => _teamName;

  set teamName(String value) {_teamName = value;}

  String get info => _info;

  set info(String value) {_info = value;}

  String get info2 => _info2;

  set info2(String value) {_info2 = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the map function to generate a list of the names only; then get the index of the team you are searching:

```
List searchTeam(String teamName){
    //retrieve from each sublist the first element (which is the name)
    int teamIndex = listOfLists.map((sublist) => sublist[0])
        //get the index of the team
        .toList().indexOf(teamName);
    return listOfLists[teamIndex];
}
```

Be careful: I didn't put any check on the structure of your list since I'm supposing that doesn't exist an empty sublist. Pay attention to that particular thing. Also I'm supposing that there's always the team searched: you should check the value of teamIndex and see if its <0. In that case the search failed so you have to decide if you want to throw an exception or adopt an alternative like returning an empty list

Comment: Bro I tried to apply the suggestion. I tried the names you said by replacing them with the names on my own list. but I could not. I still can't use the where () method. If you have time, can you write the full answer?

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use a where: the local field teamIndex is your "where". Inside teamIndex the function I wrote should store the index of the team you are searching for.
By doing return listOfLists[teamIndex] you return the list containing the information related to the team you are searching for. If you just need to get the list that's the way (do not omit the return statement!), otherwise if you need to return something else tell me and I'll try to update the solution.